# Get date of the previous day in Oracle

Tags: oracle, date, truncate

I need to bring the day immediately preceding date in Oracle using a truncate but not how. He was using the following line but bring me some records for the current day of execution and should not be. Neceisto only the previous day; investigation found the truncate with dates in Oracle but not how to use it.

```
and fnxs.FECHA_INGRESO BETWEEN (TO_CHAR (SYSDATE-1, 'DD-MON-YY')) AND (TO_CHAR (SYSDATE, 'DD-MON-YY'));
```

I appreciate your help

Comment: Do you actually want yesterdays records?  You accepted an answer which can return today's records.

Comment: Do not store dates in `varchar` columns. You should fix that as soon as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `BETWEEN` with dates in Oracle is generally a bad idea.  I see it all the time, and most of the time people get it wrong (like in the accepted answer above).  Even when they fully understand that the two dates are included, they still make logical errors because they forget about timestamps.

The OP is asking for yesterday dates.  The following sql shows that today falls within "BETWEEN TRUNC( SYSDATE ) - 1 AND TRUNC( SYSDATE )"

```
with adate as (
    select trunc(sysdate) today from dual
) select today from adate where today between trunc(sysdate) -1 
and trunc(sysdate);
```

16-Apr-15 00:00:00
[returns the record for today]

I find it easier to be correct with dates when you're more explicit about the end points:

```
SELECT * from your_table
WHERE fnxs.FECHA_INGRESO >= TRUMC(SYSDATE) - 1
AND fnxs.FECHA_INGRESO < TRUNC(SYSDATE);
```

Upon looking closer, the OP's date-like column *might* be a VARCHAR2 (could still be a date that was implicitly cast in the comparison he gave).  If it is a VARCHAR, then it needs to be converted first (using an appropriate format string):

```
SELECT * FROM your_table
WHERE TO_DATE(fnxs.FECHA_INGRESO, 'DD-MON-YY') >= TRUMC(SYSDATE) - 1
AND TO_DATE(fnxs.FECHA_INGRESO, 'DD-MON-YY') < TRUNC(SYSDATE);
```

Comment: "*Using BETWEEN with dates is generally a bad idea*" - with *real* dates it isn't. Unfortunately, Oracle's `date` is really a `timestamp` (or `datetime`) it doesn't have a "real" date (i.e. a date and only a date, not a time part with it).

Comment: Ok, I'll better qualify my statement.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name:  Even without timestamps, the other answer is wrong though.  I suppose I should maybe say that many people don't understand that `BETWEEN` includes the endpoints.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your column is of type `DATE`

```
SELECT *
FROM   TABLE_NAME
WHERE  FECHA_INGRESO >= TRUNC( SYSDATE ) - 1
AND    FECHA_INGRESO <  TRUNC( SYSDATE );
```

If it is a character string then:

```
SELECT *
FROM   TABLE_NAME
WHERE  TO_DATE( FECHA_INGRESO, 'DD-MON-YY' ) = TRUNC( SYSDATE ) - 1;
```